# Why does my compiler go in an infinite loop with c++(binary search)?

Tags: c++, iteration, binary-search

When I try to run my code, the terminal outputs a compiler line and than goes blank. Why does my terminal go blank? And why is it in an infinite loop?

**Here is the code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int biSearch(int list[] ,int lenght,int t);

int main() 
{

    int nums[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    int func_return = biSearch(nums,10,7);
    cout << func_return << endl;

    if(func_return != -1)
    {
        cout << "index: " << func_return << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "not found" << endl;
    }

}

int biSearch(int list[],int lenght,int t) 
{
    int f = 0;
    int l = lenght - 1;
    int m = (l - f) / 2;


    while(f<=l)
    {
        if (list[m] == t)
        {
            return m;
        }

        else
        {
            if (t < list[m])
            {
                l = m - 1;
                m = (l - f) / 2;
            }

            else
            {
                f = m + 1;
                m = (l - f) / 2;
            }
        }
    }

    
    return -1;
}
```

**The output of the terminal before it breaks:**

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

Experimente a nova plataforma cruzada PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS D:\Docs\CodeProjects\Nova pasta> cd "d:\Docs\CodeProjects\Nova pasta\" ; if ($?) { g++ hw.cpp -o hw } ; if ($?) { .\hw }
```

After this output, the terminal just prints a singular blank line.. **Why does my compiler go in an infinite loop?**

Comment: Run the program in whatever debugger came with your tools (and get different tools to use for debugging if you didn't get a debugger). When the program looks like it's stuck in the loop, pause the program and "step" through the code until you loop around a few times or see why the program's stuck in the loop. Use what you learned to work backwards to understand how the program got stuck in that unwanted state. Drop little tests you can place a "breakpoint" on to help you jump quicly to points of interest you want a closer look at..

Comment: While I am sure you believe your background story is compelling, your question would be improved if it omitted your history (or at least moved it to the end of the question). See [ask], in particular the parts that talk about getting right to the point, as if you are writing for busy people who might take but a few seconds to determine if this question falls into their areas of expertise. (In this case, they might read as far as *"I was studying python"* -- how does that help someone determine what expertise this question calls for?)

Comment: it is not your compiler but the command `.\hw` that does not terminate. Try `g++ hw.cpp -o hw` as a single command

Answer (score 4):

Here's your real bug:

`int m = (l - f) / 2;`

Ask yourself this. Does `(l-f)/2` accurately compute the midpoint index between `l` and `f` ?  Let me know if you don't figure it out and I'll give another hint.

Comment: Oh thaks for helping me notice it, the formula would be m = (f + l) / 2; right? realy nice and creative way of answearing the question :)

Comment: Also would i be able to solve the other bug by simply returing list[0] if length == 1?

Comment: Nvr mind tried a length 1 list and the bug didnt happen

Comment: @cachaçeirosdohawaii - oh nevermind, I didn't see the `(f <= l)` comparison, I thought it might be `(f < l)`.

Comment: And yes, `(f+l)/2` is a better equation for getting the midpoint.